# GridDB Java - Performance degradation with large transactions

Tags: java, database-performance, griddb

I am working on a Java project that utilizes GridDB for data management, and I'm encountering a performance issue when dealing with large transactions. Here's a detailed description of the problem.

- When attempting to process large transactions in GridDB, I've observed a substantial degradation in performance.
- The slowdown is most pronounced when performing bulk inserts, updates, or deletes on a sizable dataset.
- This performance issue is negatively impacting the responsiveness and efficiency of our application.

**Environment:**

- GridDB version: GridDB version 4.2.1
- Programming language: Java
- Server specifications: Intel Core i7 CPU, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD

**Additional Information:**

- I'm seeking insights, suggestions, or specific techniques to optimize GridDB's performance when dealing with large transactions.
- Are there particular GridDB configuration settings that I should adjust?
- Is there a recommended approach for efficiently handling large data loads?
- Any advice on improving GridDB's overall performance in such scenarios would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:
Here's a simplified code sample of how I'm working with GridDB:

```
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridDBPerformanceIssue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactory.getInstance();
            GridStore store = factory.getStore(new GridStoreInfo());
            // ... (rest of your code)
        } catch (GSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- I've optimized the database schema to the best of my knowledge.
- I've fine-tuned SQL queries to minimize the impact.
- I've reviewed the GridDB documentation and tried to apply recommended best practices.